# display none the div if content is null

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a content that is wrap in a div generated by a `the_content`. it is possible that the content is null it generates nothing but i want to hide the div that is wrapping the content.

What I have done is put it in a loop now once I have declared the `$pageContent` its not working or the declaration of the variable is generating it although its my main point is to store the value to that function. Below is what I have done.

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix row">
    <div id="main" class="col col-md-12 clearfix" role="main">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();
                the_content();
                $thispage=$post->ID;
            }
        } ?>
        <div class="page-header"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>

    <?php $childpages = query_posts('orderby=menu_order&order=asc&post_type=page&post_parent='.$thispage);
        if($childpages){ 
                echo '<div class="page-content">';
                foreach ($childpages as $post) :
                setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div class="page-image img-responsive"><?php the_post_thumbnail(full);?></div>
                    <?php 
                        if ($pageContent->the_content != '') {
                            echo '<div class="page-content">'.$pageContent.'</div>'; }
                        }   
                    ?>
                </article>      
         <?php
              endforeach;
                echo '</div>';
         } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is whats not working.

```
<?php 
                        if ($pageContent->the_content != '') {
                            echo '<div class="page-content">'.$pageContent.'</div>'; }
                        }   
                    ?>
```

Generally I would replace the code with this in order to work. which is generating the div even in null condition of the content.

```
<div class="page-content"><?php the_content();?></div>
```

and this also works which is I think should be wrong. the $`pageContent = the_content();` is generating the content rather than the if condition.

```
                <?php 
                    $pageContent = the_content();
            if ($pageContent != '') {
                echo '<div class="page-content">'.$pageContent.'</div>'; 
            }   
                ?>
```

Comment: `$pageContent->the_content != ''` indicates `$pageContent` to be an object. Why do you try to output `$pageContent` instead of `$pageContent->the_content`?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I honestly don't get what you mean since I have no knowledge about php. What I was think is using the `$pageContent` to insert it in the `echo`. Now the problem is why the if statement is not wrapping my content to the div i've `echo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please add below php code it works.

```
<?php if( get_the_content() ) : ?>
    <div class="page-content"><?php the_content();?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, `the_content()` echos the content rather than returning it. Read the [WordPress manual](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/). You will find the source code:

```
function the_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false) {
  $content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );

  /**
   * Filter the post content.
   *
   * @since 0.71
   *
   * @param string $content Content of the current post.
   */
  $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
  $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
  echo $content;
}
```

As you can see, it outputs the content. You can use use `get_the_content()` to check if there is any. Then output your `<div>` or what ever you want, call `the_content()` and after that output `</div>`. Do not try to concatenate `the_content` into a string.

You might also want to store `get_the_content()` into a variable and apply filters and do the string replace yourself within the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

if `the_content()` generates the content why don't you check using it instead

so instead of

```
        <?php 
            if ($pageContent->the_content != '') {
                echo '<div class="page-content">'.$pageContent.'</div>'; 
            }   
        ?>
```

try the code below

```
            <?php 
                if (the_content() != '') {
                    echo '<div class="page-content">'.the_content().'</div>'; 
                }   
            ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain why the div is not generating and wrapping the content even if it is not null? basically that's what happening on the 2nd code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code this will work for you.

```
<?php if(the_content() ) { ?>
    <div class="page-content">
<?php the_content();?>
</div>
<?php } else{
echo "div not showing";
} ?>
```